# Need running total in Sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, compact-framework, system.data.sqlite

I have a Sqlite database with a table containing financial transactions. Pertinent columns are date, PO#, and debit and credit amounts. I need to display these transactions and have a running total calculated based on an arbitrary starting balance (which is always the first record).

I created a view based on this query:

```
SELECT t1.[ID], t1.[Date], t1.[PO], t1.[Debit], t1.[Credit],
       ( SELECT SUM( t2.[Credit] ) - SUM ( t2.[Debit] ) 
         FROM [Transaction] t2 
         WHERE t2.[ID] <= t1.[ID] ) AS [Balance]
FROM   [Transaction] t1
```

and it works. Problem is, sometimes I need to order by date and/or PO# and when I do, while the Balance column value is correct, it's out of order. Also, I'll need to filter by date, so I don't believe I can use a computed column in the Transaction table.

I've looked into using the `ROWID` value, but no change. As far as I can find, Sqlite doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`. I've spent a couple days trying to wrap my head around this with no luck.

This a .NET Compact Framework app, Sqlite ADO.NET version 1.0.66 (not sure what version of the Sqlite engine that is).

Comment: The best way to keep a balance in a banking database is to [record the balance after each transaction](http://yourcodeisshowing.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/the-bankers-database/).

Comment: I don't disagree. I've seen mention elsewhere of using a trigger to update the Transaction table, but not sure how to go about doing it. Guess it's time to Google some more.

Comment: I guess you could have a trigger to update the balance after each transaction, given that you have a balance field in your Transaction table.

Comment: Add a column to your transaction table to store the balance. Update your code to store the balance on every transaction. Update the historic data from the data in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was indeed to add a Balance field to the table, and update it via triggers when records are added/edited/deleted. Turns out my real question wasn't so much how to do a running total, but best practice for doing what I was trying to do, which was a banker's database as suggested by MPelletier. I found examples of the triggers I needed in [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg52737.html) which, with a little tweaking, I got to do what I needed. Consequently, I no longer require the view since its only purpose was for the running total.